# Counterexample to Liouville in reals

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, examples-counterexamples

I know if $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is bounded and holomorphic, then it is just the constant function. My question is for $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ what would be a good example where this fails. I know trig functions are bounded and have infinitely many derivatives so would $f(x):= \sin x$ work where $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Comment: $1/(1+x^2)$ is another good one and it (and all its derivatives) go to zero at infinity

Comment: I like $f(x)= e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: @Conrad and Torsten Schoeneberg both excellent examples you have no idea how much these all means thanks an amount greater than aleph 1 lol.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg thanks so much! I always love seeing more examples :) much appreciated!